# Want to make a gauge view with indicate arrow and over gauge view display circle which indicate progress

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, gauge, speedometer

[image: gauge view with arrow and over gauge view white circle]

As per the image, Arrow-based works but now how to add one more white circle over gauge View and move the same as a white arrow.

Click here for [Project](https://github.com/HarshadYb/HVGaugeView)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - something I can directly paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have updated, pls you can get the project from the link.

Comment: Your question should be self-contained. I should not need to visit a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to reproduce the Indicator of the gauge I would suggest you to use a Shape like this one:

```
struct IndicatorShape: Shape {
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in
            let width = rect.width
            let height = rect.height
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
        }
    }
    
}
```

And then use it in your code as any other View. To add a Circle over your indicator you could use a simple overlay. Also, you need a masking effect to show the advancement of your gauge.
It's a bit complicated and require some fine tuning... Here's the code:

```
struct MeterReadiness : View {
//speedometerBgColor
let colors = [Color.red,Color.yellow,Color.green,Color.blue]
@State var progress : CGFloat = 0.0

var body: some View{
    
    GeometryReader {
        let size = $0.size
        
        
        ZStack{
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.0, to: 0.5)
                .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 10)
                .frame(width: 280, height: 280)
            
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: self.setProgress())
                .stroke(AngularGradient(gradient: .init(colors: self.colors), center: .center, angle: .init(degrees: 180)), lineWidth: 10)
                .frame(width: 280, height: 280)
            
            ZStack{
                
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0.0, to: 0.5)
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 10)
                    .frame(width: 280, height: 280)
                
                
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: self.setProgress())
                    .stroke(AngularGradient(gradient: .init(colors: self.colors), center: .center, angle: .init(degrees: 180)), lineWidth: 10)
                    .frame(width: 280, height: 280)
                
            }
            /// Mask the red gauge with the blue one
            .mask {
                /// To make the blue advance
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: (progress / 2) + 0.002)
                    .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 40)
            }
            
        }
        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 180))
        .overlay {
            /// Custom Indicator
            IndicatorShape()
                .fill(.black)
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    /// Circle at the base of the Indicator
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.purple)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .offset(y: 10)
                } //: Overlay Indicator Bottom Dot
                .frame(width: 25, height: 110)
                .padding(.top, 40)
                .offset(y: -5)
                .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                    /// Here is the Circle above the Indicator
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .offset(y: 0)
                        .shadow(radius: 1)
                }
            /// These two lines are to make the Indicator and the Circle move
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90), anchor: .bottom)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(progress * 180), anchor: .bottom)
                .offset(y: -75)
        } //: Overlay Indicator
        .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height, alignment: .center)
        
    }
    .padding(.bottom, -140)
    .onAppear(perform: {
        withAnimation(Animation.default.speed(0.1)){
            self.progress = 1
        }
    })
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    
}
```

In order for this to work I had to set the progress to be in the 0-1 range. You can easily convert that to show 0-100.
You may need to adjust the offset position of the circle of course and make any other adjustment you need.
Here's the result:

[image: Gauge with masking effect]

Let me know if this worked for you!

Comment: This is the actual problem which is not happening

Comment: What do you mean? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: No, the dot and indicator not moving in the same

Comment: Did you add the rotation effect at the end using the progress? Also, in my case progress varies from 0-1.

Comment: And your code is not reproducible, so I don't know at what point are you stuck.

Comment: I have updated, pls you can get the project from the .

Comment: I've updated the answer. Have a look, please.